# How to determine if a directory path was SUBST'd

Tags: c#, security, directory

How can I figure out if a file is in a folder that has been [SUBST'ed](https://ss64.com/nt/subst.html) or is located in a user folder using C#?

Comment: I don't get what you mean by "subst'd" or "user folder"

Comment: `subst` is a dos command that will create an alias for a directory (eg. `subst T: C:\workareas` will create a new drive that points to C:\workareas)
for user folder, i'm looking to find out if its in the `C:\Documents and Settings\%username%` cleanly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to P/Invoke QueryDosDevice() for the drive letter.  Subst drives will return a symbolic link, similar to \??\C:\blah.  The \??\ prefix indicates it is substituted, the rest gives you the drive+directory.

Answer (score 4):

This is the code I use to get the information if a path is substed:
(Some parts come from [pinvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.querydosdevice))

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
static extern uint QueryDosDevice(string lpDeviceName, StringBuilder lpTargetPath, int ucchMax);

public static bool IsSubstedPath(string path, out string realPath)
{
    StringBuilder pathInformation = new StringBuilder(250);
    string driveLetter = null;
    uint winApiResult = 0;

    realPath = null;

    try
    {
        // Get the drive letter of the path
        driveLetter = Path.GetPathRoot(path).Replace("\\", "");
    }
    catch (ArgumentException)
    {
        return false;
        //<------------------
    }
    
    winApiResult = QueryDosDevice(driveLetter, pathInformation, 250);

    if(winApiResult == 0)
    {
        int lastWinError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(); // here is the reason why it fails - not used at the moment!

        return false;
        //<-----------------
    }

    // If drive is substed, the result will be in the format of "\??\C:\RealPath\".
    if (pathInformation.ToString().StartsWith("\\??\\"))
    {
        // Strip the \??\ prefix.
        string realRoot = pathInformation.ToString().Remove(0, 4);

        // add backshlash if not present
        realRoot += pathInformation.ToString().EndsWith(@"\") ? "" : @"\";

        //Combine the paths.
        realPath = Path.Combine(realRoot, path.Replace(Path.GetPathRoot(path), ""));

        return true;
        //<--------------
    }

    realPath = path;

    return false;
}
```

From a comment, by @rrreee. I haven’t checked it but sounds usefull:

```
Handy tip: lastWinErr will be 2, if the drive letter in path is not mapped
```

Comment: be sure you have in your class

    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
Otherwise you will get error.

Comment: Handy tip: lastWinErr will be 2, if the drive letter in path is not mapped.

Answer (score 2):

If SUBST is run without parameters it produces a listing of all current substitutions. Get the list, and check your directory against the list.

There is also the issue of mapping a volume to a directory. I have never attempted to detect these, but the mount point directories do show up differently than regular directories, so they must have a different attribute of some kind, and that could be detected.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a few choices --

Via System.Management classes:
http://briancaos.wordpress.com/2009/03/05/get-local-path-from-unc-path/

Or

Via P/Invoking this MAPI function:
ScUNCFromLocalPath
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc842520.aspx

Comment: this looks promising, looking into it