# How to use the foxtools.fll in Winforms?

Tags: c#-4.0, visual-foxpro

I have been working in VFP to WPF migration project.While converting the code encountered "foxtools.fll" in foxpro code. I have searched alot on google.
Can any one tell me the use of foxtools.fll? How can we use them in C# ?

Comment: Don't know if you already found this or if it is of help http://www.foxtools.com/foxtoolsfll-help-file

Comment: I have already refered this link also.

Answer (score 0):

I believe many of those elements are already available within C# to some extent.  What you may want to do is create your own C# static class and have the functions by the same name reference as they are in VFP, then call with the same parameters as if from VFP, but handle based on C#...  Something like

```
public static class FoxTools
{
   // since DriveType is a class, changed method to GetDriveType
   public static DriveType GetDriveType( string DriveLetterToTest )
   {
        Sample code to detect drive types
        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396634/how-can-i-determine-if-a-given-drive-letter-is-a-local-mapped-usb-drive/4396692#4396692
   }

   public static string DefaultExt( string ThisFileName, string TryThisExt )
   {
       if( Path.GetExtension( ThisFileName ).Length > 0
          return ThisFileName;

      return ThisFileName + TryThisExt;
   }

   public static string ForceExt( string ThisFileName, string ForceThisExt )
   {
      return Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension( ThisFileName ) + ForceThisExt;
   }

   public static string ForcePath( string ThisFileName, string ForceThisPath )
   {
      return ForceThisPath + Path.GetFileName( ThisFileName );
   }

   // many others simple to get to, looking at the "Path." object reference for things
   // associated with file names, paths, extensions, etc..


}
```

Note, you don't have to do EVERY function, just those that you are actually utilizing from the FoxTools.fll.  After coding in C# for a while, things get much easier to find the C# equivalents to VFP calls in many cases.  Sometimes easier, sometimes a bit more effort but still doable.