# Search for config file upon login

Tags: c#

I have a quiz that has a login feature but, when you change pc you must also change the drive the file is located e.g D drive, E drive etc...

Currently its set to F. Is there something i can add that will make it automatically search each drive for the file?

Here is my code

```
if (File.Exists(@"F:\C# Completed quiz\adam new\Mario quiz\bin/PlayerDetails.txt"))
{

    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"F:\C# Completed quiz\adam new\Mario quiz\bin/PlayerDetails.txt");
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to store the file in a commonly accessible location, such as `%appdata%` (or `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)` in c#)?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you just put it in the AppData or MyDocuments folder:

```
string filename = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "C# Completed quiz","adam new","Mario quiz","bin","PlayerDetails.txt");
//or Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments

if (File.Exists(filename))
{
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filename);
}
```

Comment: You need a bit of [`System.IO.Path.Combine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of concatenating strings.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Resource file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy(v=vs.90).aspx) to store your **txt** inside the application or just distribute it with your executable. To add resource file:

1. Right click on your project and select **Properties**
2. Go to **Resources** tab and create new file
3. Click **Add resource** -> **Add Existing File...**
4. Choose your text file and click **Open**

The file can now be accessed like string:

```
var lines = Properties.Resources.PlayerDetails;
```

If the file is in the same folder as your **exe** then you can access it in this way:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("PlayerDetails.txt");
```

Edit: Note the comment below if you prefer to use this method.

Comment: Unless the app is installed in a location that needs elevated permissions for writing to (like, for instance, `Program Files`). Not a great idea.

Answer (score 0):

you need to enumerate the hard drives on the system and inspect them one at a time

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getlogicaldrives(v=vs.110).aspx

shows how to enumerate the hard drives on the system

This answer uses what looks like a better way

[How can I determine if a given drive letter is a local/mapped/usb drive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396634/how-can-i-determine-if-a-given-drive-letter-is-a-local-mapped-usb-drive)

Once you know a drive is a mounted drive the you should look at `<drive>:/<your path>`