# subst drive - DirectoryNotFoundException

Tags: c#, mount, getdirectories, subst

I'm trying retrieve the sub directory list of a subst drive (D:) using C# - DirectoryInfo.GetDirectories() but a DirectoryNotFoundException is thrown.

Does this not work with subst drives?

Is it possible to create/mount a folder on my server as the D: drive (alternative to subst) and access it via GetDirectories()?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3016223/how-to-determine-if-a-directory-path-was-substd

Comment: Did you run the `subst` command as the same windows user you're running the c#-program with?

Comment: @codemonkey : that was an useful tip . I just ran out into this problem and it seems to the user issue. Thanks.