# Drive created by SUBST (Windows 10) Not Reporting Full Path to QueryDosDevice()

Tags: vb.net, winapi, file-io, windows-10, subst

### EDIT - LOOKS LIKE I FOUND THE PROBLEM

Sorry. Apparently it was all my fault. See my self-written answer below for details.

---

I'm working on a test for a [`SUBST`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/subst)-ed drive that's included as a part of a larger method that tests a string to ensure that it's (at least, possibly) a valid path. After a bit of validation, the "encapsulating" method converts the string to a UNC or absolute path, depending on the path that's passed in, to return elsewhere.

A couple of examples:

- For drive `U:\` mapped to `\\SERVERNAME\Share`, using the `\HKCU\Network\` key in the Windows Registry to find network drive mappings on the local computer, `U:\PublicFolder\SomeFile.txt` becomes `\\SERVERNAME\Share\PublicFolder\SomeFile.txt`
- Alternately, `C:\SomeFolder\SomeFile.txt` is left unchanged because (as determined within the method) it's an absolute path to a local, physical drive.

So far, most of this appears to be working well and as expected, but I'm encountering an issue with regards to drives created by the `SUBST` command in Windows 10 (*at least - I haven't run any tests under another OS at this time because I don't have another available to me right now*).

To be honest, I don't have much experience with the `SUBST` command and don't use it very often, so, at first, I was having trouble even getting the drive to show up correctly in Windows. After reading through a discussion on the Microsoft Community page ([Windows 10 issue "Subst" command doesn't work](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files/windows-10-issue-subst-command-doesnt-work/d38c5130-b2b1-4a85-8ef6-ef1206c3174c)), I was finally able to get the drive set up "properly" (*don't use an elevated command prompt, BTW*), but the code I'm using to test for a `SUBST`-ed drive - converted to VB.NET from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37278193/2569697) - was still not resolving the full path correctly.

Here's the converted code I'm using (I intend to do some "tweaking" later once I have everything working, but this is the current state):

```vb
<DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True)>
Private Shared Function QueryDosDevice(ByVal lpDeviceName As String, ByVal lpTargetPath As System.Text.StringBuilder, ByVal ucchMax As Integer) As UInteger
End Function

Private Shared Function IsSubstPath(ByVal pathToTest As String, <Out> ByRef realPath As String) As Boolean
    Dim PathInformation As System.Text.StringBuilder = New System.Text.StringBuilder(260)
    Dim DriveLetter As String = Nothing
    Dim WinApiResult As UInteger = 0

    realPath = Nothing

    Try
        ' Get the drive letter of the path
        DriveLetter = IO.Path.GetPathRoot(pathToTest).Replace("\\", "")
    Catch ex As ArgumentException
        Return False
    End Try

    WinApiResult = QueryDosDevice(DriveLetter, PathInformation, 260)

    If WinApiResult = 0 Then
        Dim LastWinError As Integer = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()

        Return False
    End If

    ' If the drive is SUBST'ed, the result will be in the format of "\??\C:\realPath\".
    If PathInformation.ToString().StartsWith("\??\") Then
        Dim RealRoot As String = PathInformation.ToString().Remove(0, 4)

        RealRoot += If(PathInformation.ToString().EndsWith("\"), "", "\")
        realPath = IO.Path.Combine(RealRoot, pathToTest.Replace(IO.Path.GetPathRoot(pathToTest), ""))

        Return True
    End If

    realPath = pathToTest
    Return False
End Function
```

Which I call like this for a drive I created using `SUBST H: D:\substtest`:

```vb
Dim TestFile As New IO.FileInfo("H:\0984\CPI.TXT")
Dim SubstPath As String = String.Empty
Dim FullPath As String = String.Empty

If IsSubstPath(FullPath, SubstPath) Then
    FullPath = SubstPath
End If
```

My expectation is that the `IsSubstPath()` method *should* return `D:\substtest\0984\CPI.TXT` via the `realPath` variable. Executing `SUBST` (without additional parameters) correctly showed the mapping in the command prompt (`H:\: => D:\substtest`). Checking the `TestFile` object while debugging shows that it's `Exists()` property returns `True`, so the file system does, apparently, know that it's there.

At this point, every time I execute the code, the `QueryDosDevice()` method call returns a value of `0`, although I get varying results from the `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()` call as I continue to try to get this working.

My first attempt after getting the `SUBST`-ed drive "properly" set up on my machine resulted in the `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()` returning error code [1008 - ERROR_NO_TOKEN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--1000-1299-) ("*An attempt was made to reference a token that does not exist*").

Further reading in the linked MS community thread indicated that running `SUBST` *twice* - *once* in a normal command prompt, and *again* in an elevated command prompt - *should* make the drive available to either a regular logged on user as well as any elevated user action. I re-ran `SUBST` in an elevated command prompt and tried again using the same testing code as above. This time, `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()` returned error code [6 - ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-) (*"The handle is invalid."*).

Thinking this particular operation *might* be dependent on the file/path actually existing on the system (as opposed to the .NET `IO.FileInfo` or `IO.DirectoryInfo` objects), I manually created the specific subfolder and file to represent what I was testing for in my code (`H:\0984\CPI.TXT`) and tried it once more (again, using the same code as above):

Once again, the `QueryDosDevice()` failed to correctly parse the real path (returned `0`), but this time the `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()` method returned a value of [0 - ERROR_SUCCESS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-) (*"The operation completed successfully."*). Thinking that, perhaps there was some "flaw" in the code that might unintentionally be skipping a step or something, I checked the `PathInformation` variable - the `Text.StringBuilder` object that holds the results of the `QueryDosDevice()` - in break mode but, alas it's also empty.

*NOTE: I also tried using a directory instead of a file, but `H:\0984\` resulted in a `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()` return value of `0` while `H:\0984` resulted in a value of `6`. Based on the previous testing, this all makes sense but it nonetheless results in an empty `PathInformation` variable (failure).*

Reading all around the Interwebz, it seems many people are experiencing a variety of issues with `SUBST`-ed drives under Windows 10, so I'm left wondering at this point if *that's* the reason for these unexpected results. Has anyone else encountered these issues and, if so, have you been able to resolve them in code?

In case it matters (as I suppose it certainly might), here are some additional details:

- I'm using Visual Studio 2017 CE and my project is compiling under .NET Framework 4.7.2
- The physical drive to which I'm creating the `SUBST` path is a RAID 1 pair of drives formatted with NTFS and has plenty of space (178 GB).
  *NOTE: I have also tried creating a `SUBST`-ed path to my OS drive (`C:\`) for the testing, but this gets the same results as above.*

If I've left anything out, or if you require further clarification, please let me know in the comments and I'll update the question as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### DOUBLE/TRIPLE/QUADRUPLE CHECK CONVERTED CODE

Looks like it all comes down to a single line of code to which I wasn't paying close enough attention (*line 14 in the code block above*):

```vb
DriveLetter = IO.Path.GetPathRoot(PathToTest).Replace("\\", "")
```

The problem here is that the `Path.GetPathRoot()` method returns the drive letter in the format `H:\` - there's *only one* backslash (`\`), so the `.Replace()` method didn't find anything to replace and was passing an "invalid" parameter value (`H:\` instead of ***`H:`***). The `QueryDosDevice()` method will apparently fail if the trailing backslash is there, so I made a quick code edit:

```vb
DriveLetter = IO.Path.GetPathRoot(PathToTest).Replace("\", "") ' <--Replace ANY/ALL backslashes
```

I again tested with my `SUBST H: D:\substtest` drive with an existing file/directory structure as above. This time, the `QueryDosDevice()` method returned a value of `19` and correctly parsed the real path as `D:\substtest\0984\CPI.TXT`.

Then, I deleted the subfolder/file I had created for testing and tried again. Again, it correctly returned the real path as `D:\substtest\0984\CPI.TXT`. So, apparently it all comes down to me overlooking a "typo" introduced during my conversion of the code from C# to VB.NET. My apologies. The full, corrected version of the converted code

```vb
<DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True)>
Private Shared Function QueryDosDevice(ByVal lpDeviceName As String, ByVal lpTargetPath As System.Text.StringBuilder, ByVal ucchMax As Integer) As UInteger
End Function

Private Shared Function IsSubstPath(ByVal pathToTest As String, <Out> ByRef realPath As String) As Boolean
    Dim PathInformation As System.Text.StringBuilder = New System.Text.StringBuilder(260)
    Dim DriveLetter As String = Nothing
    Dim WinApiResult As UInteger = 0

    realPath = Nothing

    Try
        ' Get the drive letter of the path without the trailing backslash
        DriveLetter = IO.Path.GetPathRoot(pathToTest).Replace("\", "")
    Catch ex As ArgumentException
        Return False
    End Try

    WinApiResult = QueryDosDevice(DriveLetter, PathInformation, 260)

    If WinApiResult = 0 Then
        Dim LastWinError As Integer = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()

        Return False
    End If

    ' If the drive is SUBST'ed, the result will be in the format of "\??\C:\realPath\".
    If PathInformation.ToString().StartsWith("\??\") Then
        Dim RealRoot As String = PathInformation.ToString().Remove(0, 4)

        RealRoot += If(PathInformation.ToString().EndsWith("\"), "", "\")
        realPath = IO.Path.Combine(RealRoot, pathToTest.Replace(IO.Path.GetPathRoot(pathToTest), ""))

        Return True
    End If

    realPath = pathToTest
    Return False
End Function
```

As I said in the question, I intend to do some "tweaking" of this method, but this ***does*** work (now).